# Find a conformal mapping from the unit disc to the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis

I think I know how to do this. I start by converting the disc into a line by $f(z) = 1/(1-z)$. Which then needs to be shifted by $-1/2$. Then rotate it by $i$ to get the upper half plane. Then do we just take the square root?

Any tips would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could (for example) use the map $z \mapsto i\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ which maps the unit disc to the upper half plane and then use $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ which maps the upper half plane to the first quadrant, proving that the indeed map to these domains, I leave to you.